# Throw an Exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arraylist

For my assignment we've been asked to add in a manual IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```java
public int get(Object[] objArr){
    size = objArr.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        if(objArr[i] < 0 || objArr[i] > objArr.length )
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("I must be greater than 0 and less than " + size);
        }
```

I'm trying to get the code to loop through the look and check for numbers less than 0 and their index is outside of the array declared by the user. I'm getting an error for my if statement, and was wondering on how I could fix that.

Comment: *"I'm getting an error"* - what error? Probably that you cannot compare `Object` and `int`?!

Comment: You appear to be confusing the `i` index in an array with `objAr[i]` which is the value in that array.

Comment: Can you tell me how this will compile if(objArr[i] < 0 || objArr[i] > objArr.length )

Comment: @luk2302 - The error said the the operator < is undefined for object and int types, but i got help thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to throw the exception when you get an input index i that is <0 or > than size of the array.

Like:

```
public void get(Object[] objArr, Integer i){
    size = objArr.length;
    if(i<0 || i >= size){
       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("I must be greater than 0 and less than " + size);
    } 
}
```

Comment: It should be `i >= size` as @xander mention

Answer (score 0):

Fist you should throw the expection before you enter the for loop and second you need to check the index, not the value of the object at the index:

```
if(i < 0 || i >= objArr.length )
```